# $E$ compact, real-valued $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous iff graph is compact - is real valued necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

**Problem**

The graph $G$ of $f$ is defined as the points $(x, f(x))$ for $x \in E$.

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, then $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous iff its graph is compact.

---

**Question**

My solution doesn't use the fact that $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ nor the fact that $f$ is a real function. Are these necessary hypotheses?

---

**My solution**

Let $Y$, some metric space, be the codomain of $f$, then $G$ is a subset of $E \times Y$. Define a metric  on $E \times Y$ - the choice of metric is irrelevant.

If $x$ is continuous because it's a polynomial, and $f(x)$ is continuous by hypothesis. Then $g := (x, f(x))$ is continuous (Theorem 4.10 in Rudin). Since $E$ is compact, so is $G$ since $g$ is a continuous mapping from $E$ to $G$.

Suppose $G$ is compact. We have $g^{-1} (x, f(x)) = x$; clearly $g^{-1}$ is bijective. The inverse of $g^{-1}$, i.e. $g$ itself, is continuous since $G$ is compact and $g^{-1}$ is bijective. Thus $f(x)$ is also continuous.

---

Is this right? I don't think we need real-valued or $E \subset \mathbb{R}$. I'm a bit skeptical because usually all given hypotheses are necessary so that the strongest possible statement is proven.

Comment: Can you elaborate why in the second direction of your proof: $g$ is continuous knowing that $G$ is compact and $g$ is bijective? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ThomasE. A continuous bijection with compact domain and Hausdorff codomain has a continuous inverse, although this should be made clearer.

Comment: No those assumptions aren't necessary, but be careful with your wording. Saying that $x$ is a polynomial doesn't make sense on an arbitrary metric space, better to say that $x \mapsto x$ is the identity function on $E$. And second, for $g := (x,f(x))$ to be continuous the metric on $E \times Y$ is clearly relevant, so you should be clear about what metric you're using.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez. You're right. $g^{-1}$ is clearly continuous as it's the restriction of a projection map on the first coordinate, but this detail is essential in order to conclude the continuity of $g$ given the other assumptions.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Is it relevant to the proof though? My proof doesn't ever use what metric is used.

Comment: Saying that $g := (x,f(x))$ is continuous requires a metric  on $E \times Y$ which is compatible with the product topology. So, yes, your proof does use it. Of course, there are different possible metrics with this property, but you should be clear that you are using such a metric.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: This works for arbitrary topological spaces, with $X\times Y$ equiped with the product topology: (a) $X$ compact and $f$ continuous implies graph compact, (b) $X$ Hausdorff and graph compact implies $f$ continuous. The proof is yours, of course.